# upgrading kubernetes operator/controller code

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

wanted to get some advice /best practices on maintaining and upgrading operators. We have an operator based on operator-sdk framework. We are looking at day 2 use cases like upgrading our custom controller code. what are the best practices of upgrading the operators? How do you handle rollback if the upgrade operation fails? any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to use [OLM](https://olm.operatorframework.io/) (**Operator lifecycle manager**) it will enable you to deliver your operators with packaging mechanisms. OLM will help you with installation, versioning, upgrades and downgrades.
It will also serve as a catalog of installed Operators in your cluster and a set of metadata about them.

You can read about the [OLM's architecture](https://olm.operatorframework.io/docs/concepts/olm-architecture/) in the documentation.